# Opens and Clicks discrepancy in IOS_APP

Tags: branch.io

Channel is email and platform is IOS_APP. If there are 800 clicks recorded and 550 opens that is an 70% open rate - IOS_Web has 800 Clicks and 2 web sessions. There are also 50 installs. That is a total of 702 sections off off 800 clicks. My question is the 98 clicks not measured in install opens or sessions. Are they peopled that failed to install the app after click?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out! Joie at Branch here!

The remaining 98 clicks are either end users that decided not to download or that downloaded after the click attribution window expired.

Please do reach out at integrations@branch.io if you have any further questions!

Have a great day!

Cheers,

Joie